# Cadastrar Produtos de Banco de Dados Externo MariaDB no Woocommerce

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce

Cumprimentos. O sistema local utiliza o banco de dados MariaDB, sabemos que existe Rest API da Woocommerce, a dúvida é se existe uma maneira de interligar os bancos de dados MariaDB com Mysql do Woocommerce para cadastrar todos os produtos no Wordpress, pois todos os produtos estão cadastrados no MariaDB, estou totalmente perdido e disposto a pagar se for preciso, em seguida postarei aqui a solução caso consiga, existe uma maneira mais simples de consultar e cadastrar os produtos através de uma Query com PHP? Segue abaixo o retorno de produtos do banco de dados local MariaDB:

Obs.: listados 2 produtos mas são centenas.

```html
Array
(
    [0] => 0014535
    [codigo_Prd] => 0014535
    [1] => BALANCA DIGITAL MULTILASER
    [Desc_prd] => BALANCA DIGITAL MULTILASER
    [2] => MONDELEZ
    [Laboratorio] => MONDELEZ
    [3] => PERFUMARIA
    [Departamento] => PERFUMARIA
    [4] => VAREJINHO
    [Familia] => VAREJINHO
    [5] => 9835647846795
    [BARRAS] => 9835647846795
    [6] => 0.0000
    [Promocao] => 0.0000
    [7] => 0.0000
    [Tabloide] => 0.0000
    [8] => 39.90
    [VlrVenda] => 39.90
    [9] => 39.90
    [MelhorValor] => 39.90
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0067845
    [codigo_Prd] => 0067845
    [1] => BOMBOM SONHO DE VALSA
    [Desc_prd] => BOMBOM SONHO DE VALSA 
    [2] => MONDELEZ
    [Laboratorio] => MONDELEZ
    [3] => PERFUMARIA
    [Departamento] => PERFUMARIA
    [4] => CHOCOLATE / BALAS / CHICLETES
    [Familia] => CHOCOLATE / BALAS / CHICLETES
    [5] => 8643751945358
    [BARRAS] => 8643751945358
    [6] => 0.0000
    [Promocao] => 0.0000
    [7] => 0.0000
    [Tabloide] => 0.0000
    [8] => 1.00
    [VlrVenda] => 1.00
    [9] => 1.00
    [MelhorValor] => 1.00
)
```

Segue também o exemplo da API para adicionar os produtos ao banco de dados da Woocommerce:

```js
const data = {
  name: "Premium Quality",
  type: "simple",
  regular_price: "21.99",
  description: "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
  short_description: "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
  categories: [
    {
      id: 9
    },
    {
      id: 14
    }
  ],
  images: [
    {
      src: "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg"
    },
    {
      src: "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg"
    }
  ]
};

WooCommerce.post("products", data)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
```

Comment: essa ferramenta fica rodando na maquina local sincronizando os estoques e preços... 
mas é possível alterar pra fazer o cadastro também... https://rovann.com.br/2020/02/10/woosync/

Comment: @RovannLinhalis o antivírus acusou arquivo infectado nessa ferramenta, é normal?

Comment: eles costumam acusar reputação baixa apenas, porque não é um arquivo conhecido... se quiser entrar em contato comigo, me manda um email

Comment: @RovannLinhalis sua ferramenta WooSync resolveu meu problema, foi a melhor, se não foi a única solução que encontramos. Muito obrigado e parabéns pela ferramenta mestre!